# Use data template based on property

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to control which DataTemplate a node used based on a property rather than the class type which is typically seen in wpf.

In my case I have a list of teams and I want to control the background of each team being listed in the listbox as well as a few other design elements such as displaying different logos based on which team. In my mind it seems easiest to just make a data template based on the team name.

How do you guys suggest I handle it. I don't want to create a class object for every entire team. However it would be ideal if a team doesn't have a design template that a default one gets used.

Either way if someone could put together a super simple example Id appreciate it considering im not sure how to do it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you described, it seems to me that those property can be hold on the `Team` class and you could display the content based on them !, but since you might need something much complicated you could use a `DataTemplateSelector` basically what you need to do is :

**First** : In resources area define the DataTemplates that you need plus a default one, in case none of the teams names matche a difined template,

lets say something like that :

```
  <Window.Resources> 
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultnDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type YourNameSpace:Team}">
        <Grid Background="LightGreen">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="DefaultnDataTemplate"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Matches}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TeamADataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type YourNameSpace:Team}">
        <Grid Background="LightCoral">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="TeamADataTemplate"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Matches}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TeamBDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type YourNameSpace:Team}">
        <Grid Background="LightBlue">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="TeamBDataTemplate"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Matches}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>        
</Window.Resources>
```

**Second** add a `DataTemplateSelector` class, the class will basically check the team name and return the appropriate `DataTemplate`:

```
 public class TeamDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate DefaultnDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate TeamADataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate TeamBDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item,
               DependencyObject container)
    {
        var teamName = (item as Team).Name;
        switch (teamName)
        {
            case "TeamA":
                return TeamADataTemplate;
            case "TeamB":
                return TeamBDataTemplate;
            default:
                return DefaultnDataTemplate;
        }

    }
}
```

**Third**, add an instance of that class to the `StaticResources`, and point it to the already defined DataTemplates :

```
 <YourNameSpace:TeamDataTemplateSelector x:Key="TeamDataTemplateSelector" TeamADataTemplate="{StaticResource TeamADataTemplate}" TeamBDataTemplate="{StaticResource TeamBDataTemplate}" DefaultnDataTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultnDataTemplate}"/>
```

Finally call the TemplateSelector in your List:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TeamDataTemplateSelector}">       
</ListBox>
```

here the model i am using in this sample :

```
public class Team
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Matches { get; set; }
}
  private ObservableCollection<Team> _teams=new ObservableCollection<Team>()
    {
        new Team()
        {
            Id="1",
            Matches = "45",
            Name = "TeamA"
        },
        new Team()
        {
            Id="1",
            Matches = "45",
            Name = "TeamB"
        },
        new Team()
        {
            Id="1",
            Matches = "45",
            Name = "TeamC"
        }
    };



    public ObservableCollection<Team> Teams
    {
        get
        {
            return _teams;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_teams == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _teams = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```